# What determines Google Drive upload speeds through a browser and what can make it faster?

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, upload

I currently have access to a Gigabit Ethernet connection and have been trying to upload many terabytes of data to a Google Drive account. I have been clicking and dragging files to Google Drive through the Google Chrome browser (heard it was faster than sync) but have noticed that my uploads tend to have a bottleneck of around 50 Mbps.

I have tried different browsers, like Firefox and Safari and have noticed small differences between them. I was wondering if there was a way to speed up uploads through the browser as it seems that Google cannot keep up with the upload speeds available through a Gigabit connection.

Is the speed somehow set by the server receiving the uploads or is the bottleneck completely determined by my browser?

Does uploading via an API command or on OS's like Linux make it faster?